# Using a Java arraylist with a menu method

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, menu, java.util.scanner

2 problems with this code:
How do I code this so that after the user has added to the arraylist 'theFruit' if they then press 'V' to view all fruit it includes the default fruit as well as the fruit they've added?

Also in the method 'AddFruit' it only allows me to add 2 fruit before printing. Why is this? Thank you in advance

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StkOv {
public static void main(String[] args) {

     TheMenu();

 }

public static void TheMenu()
{


         String Customer[] = new String[10]; 

     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

          String option; 
          do {   // loop back to here as long as Q isn't selected           
              System.out.println("\nMenu");
              System.out.println("V: Views all fruit");
              System.out.println("A: To add a fruit to the list");
          System.out.println("Q: To exit");

          option = input.next();  

          if (option.charAt(0) == 'V' ) 
          { 
              viewAllFruit(Customer);
              } 


          if (option.charAt(0) == 'A' ) 
          { 
              AddFruit(Customer);
          }

          }
          while (option.charAt(0) != 'Q');

          }


    public static void viewAllFruit(String CustomerRef[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> theFruit = new ArrayList<String>();

        theFruit.add("Plums");
        theFruit.add("Grapes");
        theFruit.add("Oranges");
        theFruit.add("Prunes");
        theFruit.add("Apples");

         int size = theFruit.size();
        for (int x = 0; x<size; x++) //for loop for fruits
        {            
            System.out.println("Fruit " + x + " is in stock " + theFruit);   
        }
        }

public static void AddFruit(String CustomerRef[])

{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList<String> theFruit = new ArrayList<String>();

    theFruit.add("Plums");
    theFruit.add("Grapes");
    theFruit.add("Oranges");
    theFruit.add("Prunes");
    theFruit.add("Apples");

    System.out.println("Enter the fruits you'd like to add and EE to exit");
    String choice = input.next();

    String EE = "Goodbye!";

    if (choice !=EE);
    {
        theFruit.add(choice);
        choice = input.next();

    }

    for (String S : theFruit)

    {
        System.out.println(S);
    }


}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Zielu Seriously can't thank you enough. Definitely going to do more research. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be more than two :)

Your fruit list should be "global" in your program so its content can be printed by viewAllFruit, and the new fruit can be added in addFruit method.

As it is now, in both methods you create new list, you add to it the "defualt" fruits, and then print the content. When the user enters its choice, you again create those list.

And remember **NEVER compare strings with == or !=** always with equals()

Below is some "cleaner" version of your code.

```
public static void List<String> initFruits() {
    ArrayList<String> theFruit = new ArrayList<String>();
    theFruit.add("Plums");
    theFruit.add("Grapes");
    theFruit.add("Oranges");
    theFruit.add("Prunes");
    theFruit.add("Apples");
    return theFruit;
}

public static void viewAllFruit(List<String> fruits,String CustomerRef[])
{
    for (String fruit : fruits) {
        System.out.println("Fruit " + fruit + " is in stock ");   
    }
}

public static void addFruit(List<String> fruits,String CustomerRef[])
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String EE = "EE"; //you assked for EE as quit but you wanted to compare with "Goodbye!";

    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter the fruits you'd like to add and EE to exit");
        String choice = input.next();


        if (choice.equals(EE)) {
           break;
        };

        fruits.add(choice);
    }
}

public static void TheMenu()
{
    String Customer[] = new String[10]; 

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    List<String> fruits = initFruits();


    String option; 
    do {   // loop back to here as long as Q isn't selected           
    System.out.println("\nMenu");
    System.out.println("V: Views all fruit");
    System.out.println("A: To add a fruit to the list");
    System.out.println("Q: To exit");

    option = input.next();  

    if (option.charAt(0) == 'V' ) 
    { 
        viewAllFruit(fruits,Customer);
    } 


    if (option.charAt(0) == 'A' ) 
    { 
        addFruit(fruits,Customer);
    }

    }
    while (option.charAt(0) != 'Q');

}
```